# Visual Studio has not IIS and FTP target in publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.5.3`

Why Does not exist IIS and FTP target in publish?
[image]
How can add IIS and FTP target to publish section?

My project is WebApi with react.